# sheepit form - show already saved form values using php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this sheepit javascript plugin, in my wordpress plugin.

http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?sec=demo2&lng=en_GB

This plugin works fine for text values. But i'm having problem when i inject select field values. Injected value not set as selected

can someone help me to inject data using api and make the select dropdown selected.?

Here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/H2j3P/2/) of my problem.

I inject select value like this

```
data: [
            {   
                'select': '5'
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a flaw in `sheepit javascript plugin`.
To make it work, you need to change line no `1070` from

```
var type = field.attr('type');
```

to

```
var type = field.prop('type');
```

in `sheepit javascript plugin` source.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/H2j3P/3/)**

Comment: Do you happen to know how to fix this in the min.js script as well?

Comment: Change the code in original file & minify it yourself again :-)

Comment: Is there a standard way to minify JS files?  I thought it was simply removing the whitespace, but when I searched for `.attr(` in the minified file it wasn't there, which is what confused me.

Comment: there are lots of ways. i use grunt plugin to minify my files. But, you can find a lot of minification tools in the web.